# Stop Scipy minimize after set time

Tags: python, scipy

I use minimize from the Scipy module on Python 3.4, specifically:

```
resultats=minimize(margin_rate, iniprices, method='SLSQP',
jac=margin_rate_deriv, bounds=pricebounds, options={'disp': True,
'maxiter':2000}, callback=iter_report_margin_rate)
```

The maximum number of iterations can be set (as above), but is there a way to tell minimize to stop searching for a solution after a given set time? I looked at the general options of minimize as well as the specific options of the SLSQP solver, but could not work it out.

Thanks

Comment: Usually you would limit search time indirectly, using the `maxiter` argument. Is there some reason why you can't just reduce `maxiter` to achieve a reasonable maximum execution time?

Comment: Thanks Ali. That's because I have a problem where each iteration can be very very long. So I would like to be able to stop the very first iteration if it exceeds a given time. Also  depending on the data fed to the solver, the duration of individual iterations will vary a lot - so indirectly controlling execution time through the number of iterations is not practical.

Comment: Umh I briefly saw an answer which I think suggested the use of the callback function to stop the solver according to the time elapsed. That sounded promising but that answer was apparently removed. Any idea why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. What you can do is start the optimizer in a separate process, keep track of how long it has been running and terminate it if necessary:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
import time
import random
from __future__ import print_function

def f(param, queue):
    #do the minimization and add result to queue
    #res = minimize(param)
    #queue.put(res)

    #to make this a working example I'll just sleep a 
    #a random amount of time
    sleep_amount = random.randint(1, 10)
    time.sleep(sleep_amount)
    res = param*sleep_amount
    queue.put(res)

q = Queue()
p = Process(target=f, args=(2.2, q))
max_time = 3
t0 = time.time()

p.start()
while time.time() - t0 < max_time:
    p.join(timeout=1)
    if not p.is_alive():
        break

if p.is_alive():
    #process didn't finish in time so we terminate it
    p.terminate()
    result = None
else:
    result = q.get()
print(result)
```

Comment: That's great. A bit more general than the alternative approach above, because would work on the first iteration.Thanks numentar.

Comment: No problem! The callback solution is also interesting but unfortunately many other scipy.optimize methods don't have the option of providing a callback function (e.g., curve_fit). This approach can be applied to any function whose execution time has to be limited. I use a similar approach to run thousands of jobs in parallel while ensuring that no single jobs gets stuck for too long.

Answer (score 12):

You can use the `callback` argument to raise a warning or exception if the execution time exceeds some threshold:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize, rosen
import time
import warnings

class TookTooLong(Warning):
    pass

class MinimizeStopper(object):
    def __init__(self, max_sec=60):
        self.max_sec = max_sec
        self.start = time.time()
    def __call__(self, xk=None):
        elapsed = time.time() - self.start
        if elapsed > self.max_sec:
            warnings.warn("Terminating optimization: time limit reached",
                          TookTooLong)
        else:
            # you might want to report other stuff here
            print("Elapsed: %.3f sec" % elapsed)

# example usage
x0 = [1.3, 0.7, 0.8, 1.9, 1.2]
res = minimize(rosen, x0, method='Nelder-Mead', callback=MinimizeStopper(1E-3))
```

Comment: thanks a lot Ali. that would work. A seems relatively simple to implement.

Comment: Very nice answer indeed. Easy to personalise also on `differential_evolution`

Comment: Hey this is from over a year ago now - apologies - but what happens if it does take too long and `pass` is called ? Does minimize just send back the `OptimisationResult` it got too ?

Comment: I had to use def __call__(self, xk=None, convergence = 0) in Python 3.11.1 for DE