# Early stopping via callback function with scipy's fmin_l_bfgs_b?

Tags: python, scipy

#### Context

I'm fitting the parameters of a neural net using scipy's [fmin_l_bfgs_b](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin_l_bfgs_b.html) port of a limited memory BFGS code. I can monitor the value of the function being optimized on separate validation data by supplying a function to the `callback` argument of the `fmin_l_bfgs_b` routine and using global variables. However, in addition to monitoring the progress on the validation data, I would also like to be able terminate the optimization if progress on the validation data has stagnated or is worsening.

#### Question

Is it possible to provide a callback function to `fmin_l_bfgs_b` that will break the while loop of the optimization routine? [See here for relevant portion of the scipy code](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.18.0/scipy/optimize/lbfgsb.py#L317-L341).

I think this question is purely a python question by considering the following:

```
def infloop(callback):
    local_variables
    while True:
        callback()
```

I'm asking if a `callback` can be provided that:

1. Can break the while loop.
2. Access and modify `local_variables` in the outer function, `infloop`.

Is this possible? Or will I have to modify the scipy source? I'm using Python 2.7.12. Scipy is 0.18.0.

Comment: Here's an example using callback: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24827245/901925; raising an error is the way to go.  The main other use of `callback` to to record intermediate results.

Comment: Nice. I thought of this, but I was so focused on `fmin_l_bfgs_b` terminating correctly, that I forgot that `callback` will be recording all the important stuff via global variables. So, it doesn't matter if bfgs raises an exception as long as it's caught.