# Tolerance for termination is ignored in scipy optimize minimize

Tags: python-3.x, optimization, scipy, scipy-optimize-minimize

I have a simple optimization problem that, with some specific data, makes **scipy.optimize.minimize** ignore the `tol` argument. From the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html), `tol` determines the "tolerance for termination", that is, the maximum error accepted for the objective function, in my understanding (am I wrong?). However in the next working example, when `tol` is set to 0.1 for example, or other small numbers, the optimizations finishes with a "Optimization terminated successfully" message even when the objective function > `tol`. Is this a bug in Scipy's method or am I misunderstanding something here?

The optimization problem: I need to make a linear combination of `var1` and `var2`, which are two time series, scaling them by parameters `Btd` and `Bta`. I need that the mean of the linear combination approximates to a target value `Target`, a scalar. So I simply minimize the absolute difference between `np.mean(Btd*var1 + Bta*var2)` and `Target`. The constraints are that the scaling coefficients must be >0 and that the ratio of means `np.mean(Btd*var1)/np.mean(Bta*var2)` should approximate to the function `gi/(1-gi)`, where `gi` is a scalar in the interval [0,1].

Reproducible code:

```py
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as opt

# The data that exactly reproduce the error:
time = np.arange(1979,2011)
var2=np.array([ 88.95705521,  74.5398773 ,  72.08588957,  65.64417178,
        50.        ,  72.39263804,  77.3006135 ,  72.08588957,
        64.41717791,  96.62576687,  69.93865031,  84.96932515,
        86.50306748,  82.20858896,  80.98159509,  73.00613497,
        66.25766871,  67.48466258,  79.75460123,  65.64417178,
        70.24539877,  84.66257669,  76.3803681 ,  83.74233129,
        83.74233129,  78.2208589 ,  88.03680982,  87.73006135,
       100.        ,  71.16564417,  73.6196319 ,  85.58282209])
var1=np.array([300.        , 420.89552239, 333.58208955, 355.97014925,
       376.11940299, 510.44776119, 420.89552239, 434.32835821,
       333.58208955, 394.02985075, 523.88059701, 411.94029851,
       353.73134328, 434.32835821, 355.97014925, 398.50746269,
       476.86567164, 371.64179104, 445.52238806, 544.02985075,
       416.41791045, 427.6119403 , 541.79104478, 579.85074627,
       429.85074627, 414.17910448, 420.89552239, 528.35820896,
       577.6119403 , 490.29850746, 600.        , 454.47761194])
X=np.transpose([var1, var2])

# Global parameters
Target = 3.0
gi = 0.7

# This model is a simple linear combination of the two time series.
def MyModel(modelparams, X, gi):
    Bta, Btd = modelparams
    Eta = Bta*X[:,0]
    Etd = Btd*X[:,1]
    Etot = Eta + Etd
    return Etot, Eta, Etd

# Objective function
def Obj(modelparams):
    Bta, Bdt = modelparams
    Etot, Eta, Etd = MyModel([Bta, Bdt], X, gi)
    return abs(np.mean(Etot)-Target)

# Ratio constraint
def Ratio(modelparams):
    import numpy as np
    Bta, Btd = modelparams
    Etot, Eta, Etd = MyModel([Bta, Btd], X, gi)
    A = np.mean(Etd)/np.mean(Eta)
    B = gi/(1-gi)
    # The epsilon comes in to loosen a bit only this constraint
    epsilon = 0.1
    return  -abs(abs(A-B)-epsilon)

# This is my solution to make the parameters different from zero.
# The ineq-type constraint makes them >=0.
def TDPos(modelparams):
    Bta, Btd = modelparams
    return Btd - 10**(-5) 
def TAPos(modelparams):
    Bta, Btd = modelparams
    return Bta - 10**(-5)

constraints=[{'type': 'ineq', 'fun': Ratio},
             {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': TDPos},
             {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': TAPos}]

# Bounds or Model Parameters
bounds=((0, None), (0, None))

# Minimize
modelparams0=[Target/np.nanmean(var1), Target/np.nanmean(var2)]
result = opt.minimize(Obj, modelparams0, 
                      tol=0.1,
                      method='SLSQP',
                      options={'maxiter': 40000 }, #,'ftol': 0.1}, 
                      bounds=bounds,
                      constraints=constraints)
print(result)
```

Prints out:

```
     fun: 3.0
     jac: array([439.92537314,  77.31019938])
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
    nfev: 20
     nit: 4
    njev: 4
  status: 0
 success: True
       x: array([0., 0.])
```

My problem:
fun: 3.0 > tol: 0.1
which is not desired.

**TL;DR**: scipy.optimize.minimize ignores the stop argument `tol`. Why?

EDIT: Moreover, the optimal solution [0, 0] ignores two of the ineq constraints, designed to make this couple of parameters > 10**(-5). Is this part of the same problem?

Comment: Whatever tol is exactly, it's solver-dependent and for sure not what you assume. For your interpretation, the solver would have to know about the lower bound of zero or would need to follow some primal dual or similar approach to obtain bounds. Often tol is a simple first order crit like abs(func(it x) - func(it x-1)). Slsqp probably does use approximated second order information. But i would not play with this pqram blindly. Your discrepance of tol and maxiter is very strange too. The former being VERY relaxed. The latter being very aggressive.

Comment: Thank you @sascha, I misunderstood the meaning of `tol`. Can you see a way to impose this threshold for termination, as an accepted error for the objective function? This is what I was aiming for with the tol.

Comment: You can hack together something using a callback; see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24827245/2320035)