# Manually Terminate Scipy Minimize()

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, scipy, minimize

I've made an app that performs multivariate constrained optimization using Scipy's `minimize()` function (using the SLSQP solver).

Some scenarios can take quite a while to optimize, and sometimes a user could inadvertently trigger a 'long' optimization process and might want a way to terminate the process, fix some inputs, and then try again.

The optimization itself is done in a 'background processs' script, which accesses a 'tasks' database table where the optimization requests are queued. I'm also using `minimize()`'s `callback()` function to update the database with progress of the optimization process.

The documentation says that for ‘trust-constr’, if the `callback()` returns `True`, then the process will terminate.
This feature would be ideal for me, however I'm using SLSQP solver (not trust-constr), and unfortunately it doesn't terminate the solver when my `callback()` returns `True`.

Are there any other ways I could write the code so that the user could terminate the optimization?

I'm fairly sure it would need to utilize the `callback()` function, so that each iteration it can check whether the user has clicked 'terminate'.
I've also tried `raise SystemExit(0)`, but that kills the whole background process. Perhaps there is a way to stop and restart my background process?

Comment: See: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24825441/2320035)